# React TypeScript Cant update custom input text value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have developed the Edit Notification page using react typescript.
I get the notification title from the database and set that value into custom input component as follow

```
let notificationTitle: string = "Notification Test"; // getting from db

  
  <FormInputText
    label={"Notification Title:"}
    value={notificationTitle}
    name={`notificationTitle1`}
    required={false}
    placeholder={
      "Text inside title tag - can include HTML text styles - bold, italic etc…"
    }
    labelClass={"full"}
  />
```

Full code link : https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-aryabhata-7lfch5?file=/src/EditPage.tsx

**Issue:**

**but I can't update the input text box value and it keeps resetting to the default value passing from the database.**

**React TypeScript code.**

*Custom Input Component*

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

interface Props {
    label: string;
    name: string;
    required? : boolean;
    placeholder: string;
    labelClass: string;
    value?: string;
}

const FormInputText: React.FC<Props> = ({
                                    label,name,required,placeholder,labelClass,rules,value
}) => {


    console.log("FormInputText",value);

    const [inputValue,setInputValue] = useState<string>("");


    useEffect(() => {
        if(inputValue == "" && value) {
            setInputValue(value);
        }else{
            setInputValue(inputValue);
        }

    });


    const changeHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        setInputValue(e.target.value);

        

    };

    return (
        <>
            <label className={labelClass}>
                <span>{label} {(required) ? <b>*</b> : <></>}</span>
                <input type="text" onChange={changeHandler} name={name}
                              placeholder={placeholder} value={inputValue}/>
            </label>

        </>



    );



}

export default FormInputText;
```

---

*Edit Page*

```
import "./styles.css";
    import FormInputText from "./inputtext.component";
    
    export default function EditPage() {
      let notificationTitle: string = "Notification Test"; // getting from db
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Edit Notification</h1>
          <FormInputText
            label={"Notification Title:"}
            value={notificationTitle}
            name={`notificationTitle1`}
            required={false}
            placeholder={
              "Text inside title tag - can include HTML text styles - bold, italic etc…"
            }
            labelClass={"full"}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `notificationTitle` is not a controlled element, from your `EditPage` you need to pass this down to your `FormInputText` component:

```
  let notificationTitle: string = "Notification Test"; // getting from db

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(notificationTitle);
```

[Code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-matsumoto-timeeo?file=/src/EditPage.tsx) (Further improvement can be made)